# For loop and accessing controls of panel in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, for-loop, controls

here i have a code that allows me to take all the text of each button control in a panel and use them as input for a `RichTextBox` but there is one problem .

`for each` button that is clicked I want the text of that button printed button am having problems with it .

i'm still a novice at vb so ...

here is the code .

```
        Dim btn As Button
    For Each btn In panel3.Controls
```

`'here i should have some soft of if statement to check if a btn is clicked`

```
        Msgbox (btn.Text) ' shows the text of the button ' should be in the if statement

    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you use the click event for the button to append text to the richTextBox.

Example:

```
Private Sub btn_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   'since each button uses this event we need to cast the sender 
   'object back to a button to get it's properties
   richtextbox1.Text &= DirectCast(sender, Button).Text
End Sub

'set the click event for all button to the same event
Private Sub form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  For Each btn In panel3.Controls
    Addhandler btn.Click, AddressOf btn_click
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI a trick to building events for multiple buttons is to select the ones you want then build the event in the designer. Note that you can have more than one event subroutine handling the same click - makes for interesting bugs!